# JSF keep session active during long running process

Tags: java, session, jsf, myfaces

We have a long-running process in our JSF (MyFaces implementation) WebApp.  It is required to have an active session during this long-running process.  Will bringing focus on various components every so often keep the session alive? (ie, clicking the background, mouse-over tabs/links, etc).  I have had success with this and don't understand why this is working.  Is this due to some sort of javascript/ajax functionality in the underlying implementation?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know JSF, but aren't sessions independent of long-running processes? i.e. as long as the session cookie hasn't expired, you're golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already explored breaking this long running process away from a web request and for some reason can't, here's your answer.

The underlying implementation won't have ajax unless you put it there.  You could do something like javascript on a timer that makes an XHR request, or you could up the session timeout in your container configuration so you don't have to do that nastiness.

Comment: Yes, it is ridiculous to have this process as web request.  Long-term solutions to this problem are being explored.  I still don't understand why clicking the background, etc during this process keeps my session alive.

Comment: I'll give you the correct answer for answering the last part of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, hope you figure out what's going on in there.